# Take only a part of text from Xpath

Tags: python, css, html, xpath

Hello i have the following html code.

```
<div class="Clr-888 Fz-12 Lh-18">
   45 answers
   <span class="Fz-14">·</span>
     <a data-rapid_p="3" class="Clr-b" href="/dir/index/discover?sid=396545232" data-ylk="slk:cat;bpos:1;cpos:1;qid:20151010204849AAebNiK;sid:396545232">Baseball</a>
     <span class="Fz-14">·</span>
   1 day ago
 </div>
```

I need to take only the data field, in the second part of the div. (1 day ago).
It's possibile to do only with **xpath**? 
Otherwise can you suggest me some easy regular expression in python to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this selector: `/div/text()[last()]`

Online demo [here](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/b62e907943e9a5008bc7c7303fd681cc).

The only issue is that it will also include the leading whitespace but you can use something like Python's `strip()` to remove it afterwards.

Comment: Thanks very precise and easy solution